# Python: UUID in a list

Tags: python, list, compare, uuid

I have a list with a uuid4 in it. I also have a string. For example:

```
list = [UUID('79d8f4b7-06a0-41d1-99d6-dd8c5308875f'), 'example1', 'example2']
string = 79d8f4b7-06a0-41d1-99d6-dd8c5308875f
```

But when I try:

```
if string in list:
    print("It's in!")
else:
    print("It's not!")
```

The output is always "it's not".

I know there is probably a data type error going on but i cant seem to find it myself. Any help is appreciated, i'm sure something this simple will be fixed within seconds, thanks in advance.

*When I type print list[0] this is what is output: 79d8f4b7-06a0-41d1-99d6-dd8c5308875f. But even when i try say "..in list[0]", it still doesn't work.*

Comment: 1st u will get NameError uuid not defined

Comment: Its already in the list, i'm not putting it into the list manually, so I don't get the error

Comment: Maybe the problem occurs cause you should write `string = '79d8f4b7-06a0-41d1-99d6-dd8c5308875f'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert [`uuid`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID) to string with `str()` function .

```
>>> import uuid
>>> x=uuid.uuid4()
>>> str(x)
'924db46b-5c51-4330-861c-363570ea9ef6'
```

and for check you need to convert string to uuid ,with `uuid.UUID` but as this function accept bytes you need to pass the bytes of your string to it   :

```
>>> my_list = [x, 'example1', 'example2']
>>> uuid.UUID(bytes=x.bytes) in my_list
True
```

Comment: The second bit has just loaded, thanks a lot, got it working!